# How to search through file and display array of tuples in Swift 2?

Tags: xcode, swift, csv, readline, getline

What is the most efficient way to search through a file with the barcode and display all the product information if it is inserted as an array of tuples? I know at this point I have to search through the file line by line, but don't know exactly how I would do it in swift 2 since I am new to it.

Here is a sample line of the .CSV file

```
TITLE,SKU,PRICE,Barcode,WEIGHT,BOX HEIGHT,BOX W_IDTH,BOX LENGTH

"Jasmine Fragrance oil diffuser",EBWD-10000,81,6793083673382,3,26,29.3,20.2
```

This is what I have so far:

```
 static func searchCode(codeNumber: String) -> [Data]
    {

        let barcodeNumber = codeNumber
        let remoteURL = NSURL(string: downloadconstants.URLConstants.productfile )
        //let characterNumber = codeNumber.characters.count
        var dataArray = [Data]()


    }
```

Anything at this point helps, a rough draft or pseudocode.

Comment: Take a look at a CSV parsing library, such as https://github.com/naoty/SwiftCSV

Comment: I recommend you use a Struct, with a name like "Product" or "Merchandise", rather than a tuple. Tuples are intended to be short lived bundles of data, primarily to return multiple things from functions. For longer used, more complex data, structs are a better choice.

Comment: @AMomchilov thanks for the link, and yeah I was thinking about using a Struct, but it took me a while to figure out what I have done so far and wouldn't want to change it at this point. But how everything is so far any way you can guide me? Thanks!

Comment: I can help you alleviate your struct related woes. Beyond that, idk what you have or how to help.